# how to click button in headless and button have div tag inside it using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

using this code for without headless approch..
website link: https://www.na-kd.com/en/sweaters?sortBy=popularity&count=108

```
try:
     element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/button')
     self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

except Exception as e:
     print('Error in clicking BTN : '+str(e))
```

Because this btn have div-tag inside it so it is not working with headless and virtual-display.

I also Try wait:

```
    try:
        element=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/button')))
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in clicking BTN : '+str(e))
```

> chromedriver --version
>   ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70
>   Google Chrome 78.0.3904.108

Comment: I can't see any button there can you send us html code of this

Comment: `<div class="qb qc qy qtl"><div class="qtm"><button class="qb6 qcf qb8 qcz qcy qd0 qcx qor qos qot qou qbh qbi qbj qcn qbk qbl qaq qat qaw qaz qco qbo qef qbm qtn qto qkm qtp qtq qtr qip qiq qir qis qts qc6 qh" type="button"><span class="qa8 qr qbk qd8 qgk qix qiy qiz qcd qce"><div class="qtt qtu qcq">Load more products</div></span></button></div><div class="qtv qtw qtx qty qan qex ql9 qtz qu0 qey qu1 qu2 qu3"></div><div class="qa6 qn9 qu4">108 of 1736 products</div></div>`

Comment: in the last of page "Load more products" button...

Comment: always put code, data and error message in question, not in comment. It will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: okay let me correct this..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the headless mode when you fire any event add window-size() Because headless browser can't recognise where to click without window size.

To click on `Load more products` button Induce WebDriverWait() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and use below **xpath**

To verify this whether button is clicked or not just scroll down the page and get the value from div tag.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Headless option with window-size()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080');

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.na-kd.com/en/sweaters?sortBy=popularity&count=108&ssr=on&loadfailure=1")

# Load more products button  

element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.//div[text()='Load more products']]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

# To verify that whether button is clicked or not
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(2) #wait for page to load
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='qa6 qmz qn0']"))).text)
```